# log file timestamp format

Tags: logging, apache-kafka

I'm trying to understand the timestamps in the server.log and controller.log logs in kafka but don't understand the last part of it. I see the time stamp in server.log like this:

```
[2017-02-01 19:14:22,075]
```

and in controller.log like this:

```
[2017-02-01 19:24:27,057]
```

what is the `,075` and `,057` represent?

Comment: Non-educated guess: milliseconds

Comment: Yes. It's milliseconds.

Comment: It is milliseconds. Have a look here as well: [Change time format to get milliseconds in Apache log files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60146227/2938810)