# Change time format to get milliseconds in Apache log files

Tags: apache, logging, time

I have used `%t` in http access log file patterns which gives the time in the following format:

`[05/Feb/2012:17:11:55 +0000]`

Is there a way to get a more precise time with milliseconds?

[Apache mod_log_config](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html) says that the format can be added the following way

> %{format}t    The time, in the form given by format, which should be in
>   an extended strftime(3) format (potentially localized). If the format
>   starts with begin: (default) the time is taken at the beginning of the
>   request processing. If it starts with end: it is the time when the log
>   entry gets written, close to the end of the request processing. In
>   addition to the formats supported by strftime(3), the following format
>   tokens are supported:

```
sec         number of seconds since the Epoch
msec        number of milliseconds since the Epoch
usec        number of microseconds since the Epoch
msec_frac   millisecond fraction
usec_frac   microsecond fraction
```

> These tokens can not be combined with each other or strftime(3)
>   formatting in the same format string. You can use multiple %{format}t
>   tokens instead.

Comment: Have you tried adding `%{msec_frac}t` to `LogFormat` line in your server configuration?

Answer (score 4):

The definition of the Apache2 logfile format can be found [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html).

As written, in the documentation you can use `%{format}t` in combination either with:

```
Format      Description
msec_frac   millisecond fraction
usec_frac   microsecond fraction
```

Or with strftime(3):

```
Format Description
%T     The time in 24-hour notation (%H:%M:%S).
%F     Equivalent to %Y-%m-%d (the ISO 8601 date format).
...
```

See the [strftime(3) documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html) for all possible placeholder.

This means for example:

- `%{usec_frac}t` > `863572`
- `%{%Y-%m-%d %T}t` > `2020-02-10 08:49:19`

Combined:

- `%{%Y-%m-%d %T}t.%{usec_frac}t` > `2020-02-10 08:49:19.863572`

Answer (score -1):

Incase if you get an Exception saying "Illegal pattern character" please refer this.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

---

Try this also `%{H:m:s:S}t`

Comment: The solution in the referred post didn't work. But your second solution did. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

I used the following pattern in my log

```
\"time\":\"%{%usec_frac}t\"
```

Which results in:

```
"time":"2018-07-04 06:09:36.066559"
```

This is running in Apache Httpd 2.4 on AWS EC2